# Angular + Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) + Cordova (android) - how to get registration on the FCM working?

Tags: android, angular, cordova, firebase, angular5

I have developed an application using Angular 5.

I have added firebase for Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I have created an account/project in Firebase Cloud Messaging and successfully installed it.

I have an API backend, which has an endpoint for storing the FCM tokens, later it will send push notifications on the devices.

I have successfully made it for "web version", when user visits the applcation in the browser, he is prompted to allow the push notifications.

Once allowed, firebase plugin registers the device and returns the token.

Then I store the token on the API server to receive push notifications in future and all works great.

Now I have a task to make the Android Application. I have successfully did this, using this tutorial: https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6

The application is working like a web version except that, there are no prompts on the device to allow push notifications, and so it doesn't send to the API it's token, so - no push notifications. And I'm stuck.

I have created an Android application on the FCM server, added the proviced .json from the FCM website into the project, installed some kind of plugin called phonegap.... but with no success in the end.

This is my very first experience in developing application for mobile phones. Any suggestions/help/tutorials/code examples etc. would be very cool.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! I stepped over your question as I'm currently trying to use the cordova push with the browser / PWA platform. Did you find docs / a tutorial how to configure the plugin that it uses FCM? I guess you only need to have the correct pushServiceURL and applicationServerKey - but where do I find these? Thanks in advance!